# Are there any male Veela?

Tags: harry-potter, magical-creatures

In Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire it is clear that the Veela strongly affect boys:

> And as the veela danced faster and faster, wild, half-formed thoughts
>   started chasing through Harry's dazed mind. He wanted to do something
>   very impressive, right now.
>
> Jumping from the box into the stadium seemed a good idea. . . but
>   would it be good enough?

Still Hermione seems to be largely unaffected:

> "Harry, what are you doing?" said Hermione's voice from a long way
>   off.

and

> "Huh?" said Ron, staring openmouthed at the veela, who had now lined
>   up along one side of the field.
>
> Hermione made a loud tutting noise. She reached up and pulled Harry
>   back into his seat.
>
> "Honestly!" she said.

Are there any male Veela that can affect girls/women the same way?

Comment: [There are no male Veela (JKR).](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/bestiary/bestiary_v.html)

Comment: That was a W.O.M.B.A.T. question (test 2)

Comment: Male Veela don't exist, but existing female Veela can be lesbian or bisexual. So, girls aren't out of luck.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [hp-lexicon.org](https://www.hp-lexicon.org/bestiary/bestiary_v.html) (thanks @randal'thor):

> Female magical beings that have the ability to drive men uncontrollably wild, especially when they ‘turn on’ their charm or perform the sensual dance for which they’re known (GF8, GF22). However, when they get angry, they turn into bird-like creatures which throw fire. A group of veela served as the mascots for the Bulgarian National Quidditch Team at the Quidditch World Cup, though they were kicked out when they distracted the referee (GF8). Veela hairs can be used as wand cores (GF18). Fleur Delacour is part veela; her wand's core is a hair from the head of her grandmother, a veela. **There are no male veela (JKR)**. (from The Lexicon page 319).

(emphasis mine)

They appear to have taken it from the W.O.W.B.A.T tests on JKR's old site.

Comment: +1 (and let's hope this doesn't fuel any rumours! ;-) ) This of course begs the question of how it's possible to have any *full-blood* Veela - or, if the offspring of a Veela and a man counts as a Veela, why Fleur isn't one.

Comment: Can you find the direct quote from JKR? The hp-lexicon site is strict on the information but it's still a fan made  work.

Comment: @vap78 Been looking, but I can't. I'll keep searching...

Comment: @randal'thor Well, thanks... I really wish I hadn't started thinking about this. Best I've got by way of explanation: Regular conception involving human-form Veela and a human male results in part-Veela/part-human offspring. Bird-form Veela lay eggs which are fertilised afterwards - by what I don't know! - which create full Veela.

Comment: Alternatively, Veela reproduce in a manner similar to humans, and have either male (fully human) or female (fully Veela) offspring. That's probably a less horrifying explanation, though I guess it wouldn't make Fleur part-Veela. I really want to stop thinking about this now.

Comment: @vap78 [source](http://www.hp-lexicon.org/wizworld/wombat/wombat2comments.html) (ctrl +f veela)

Comment: @AnthonyGrist there are [female-only species](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Mexico_whiptail) in the real world. So it is possible even without magic.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parthenogenesis

Comment: Fleur can be part-Veela. Her father is the offspring of a Veela and a man (and thus a normal man), and her mother is a normal woman. She is 1/4 Veela in terms of ancestry, but not a Veela herself.

Comment: Note that "víla" (pronounced like the English word "Veela") is the Czech word for a mythical being commonly translated to English as "fairy". In the traditional Czech (and perhaps other slavonic) folklore, these were strictly females.

Answer (score -2):

A purely theoretical answer, but it could be that the Veela has a male counterpart species that is simply called something else, and has an alternative transformation. This is an interesting fantasy trope.

It could also be based on the peacock, while the female is called a peahen. Furthermore, the peacock uses it's feathers to "show off" and have the female choose it, similar to the feeling the Veela is described making the males feel. Overall, I am positive that there must be a male counterpart to the Veela, only with an alternative name and slightly different transformation.

Comment: Not sure the peacock / peahen example works as evidence for a special Veela counterpart.  The spectacular peacock has that awesome tail, but the peahen is just some piddly bird that makes people at the zoo go "aw crap, where's the other one?"  If anything, your example suggests that an ordinary wizard *is* the counterpart to a Veela, since the Veela make ordinary wizards feel that way.  Probably Muggles too.